# Search for a pattern and replace the full line in text file using Perl

Tags: perl

I need a function to search for a pattern in a text file and replace the entire line with another string. The equivalent function of sed is like the following.

```
sed -i '/user_5/c\user_5|age-1|email5@sample.com|state-1' data.property
```

The data file will look like the following.

```
user_1|age-1|email1@sample.com|state-1
user_5|age-1|email5@sample.com|state-5
user_4|age-4|email4@sample.com|state-4
```

A function is needed in the Perl script. What is a syntax for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Perl code on the command line:

```
perl -i.bak -lpe '$_ = q(user_5|age-1|email5@sample.com|state-1) if /^user_5/' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `-i`: Does changes in-place. `.bak` allows you to retain the original file as backup.
- `-l`: Chomps the newline and places it back during print.
- `-p`: Creates an implicit `while(<>) { print }` loop.
- `-e`: Tells Perl to execute the code that follows it.

To do it in a Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = "file";  # Path to your file

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';

while (<>) {
    print and next unless /^user_5/;
    print q(user_5|age-1|email5@sample.com|state-1), "\n";
}

#unlink "$file$^I";  # Uncomment if you don't want a backup
```

Comment: It is giving a syntax error while place inside perl script. do we have to modify the syntax to use on perl script?

Comment: @AgapetosJustus It was meant to be ran on the command line directly. If you want a script, I have added that for you. Check the updated solution.

Comment: The answer with revision 2 is working. But edited one which display now not working. If you can change to that working answer it would be useful to the people who refer the post.

Comment: @AgapetosJustus Done! Though it shouldn't have mattered. I tested all revisions.

Comment: I have put a flag in the question. As changed no need of that flag.

Answer (score 0):

`perl -lne 'if (/user_5/) { print "user_5|age-1|email5\@sample.com|state-1" } else { print }'` is one way to do it.